# Why no race condition when incrementing variable from two different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just learned about race conditions and I wanted to imagine a simple race condition so I wrote a small program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

int var = 0;

void increment()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<1000; i++)
    {
        var++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(increment);
    thread t2(increment);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout << "var : " << var << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
var : 2000
```

However, I was expecting it to be less since maybe the two threads load `var` at the "same time", say they both load 24 and then they both increment from 24 to 25 and not one from 24 to 25 and the other from 25 to 26 and repeat this "mistake" many times so the final value of `var` would be less than 2000. Is the ()++ operator atomic? Is there an easy "fix" to see a race condition here?

Comment: A race condition does not have to always manifest itself. And with code as simple as this it's possible that the compiler simply replaces your entire loop with a `var += 1000;` in which case a race condition will be even harder to reproduce

Comment: Undefined Behaviour includes appearing to work (until it does not). Given the low loop condition `t1` probably completes before `t2` starts.  Another possibility is that the optimiser has removed the loop completely replacing it with `var+=1000;` leaving even less chance to show the data-race.

Comment: @RichardCritten, you are probably right, I tried bigger and bigger numbers instead of 1000 and starting from 1000000 I start to have lower results as expected. Thank you

Comment: One lesson you can learn from this exercise is, you cannot rely on testing to find race conditions. The code that passes every test you can think to throw at it today on your own machine may fail next month when it runs on customer's machines or when you deploy it to the "live" servers if its correctness depends on a race condition. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: @SolomonSlow, thank you for the heads up, for the moment I am just starting but I guess I will need to find another way to test in the future then

Comment: Things that increase the change of getting the wrong answer: incrementing a billion times instead of just a thousand; making sure optimizations are turned off; incrementing by 5 instead of 1 (note that 2 billion times 5 will overflow 32-bit `int`)

Comment: @roi_saumon: A great tool for detecting data race bugs is [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html), supported by both gcc and clang; just use `-fsanitize=thread`.  I ran it on your program and it flags the data race immediately.

Comment: @user253751, Re, "incrementing by 5," In many applications, being off by one is just as bad as being off by any other number.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The x86 has an "increment by 1" instruction and I thought that avoiding that instruction might increase the time between read and write